# How to grab Chinese characters from HTML code using JAVA inputStream?

Tags: java, utf-8, web-scraping, inputstream, decode

I would like to download some data from a website using the following methods.

It has no problem downloading **English**/number content, but it won't generate the correct **Chinese** character when I try to grab Chinese content.

```
String url = "https://hk.finance.yahoo.com/q/ct?s=1928.HK";         
URL yahooUrl = new URL(url);
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yahooUrl.openStream()));
String line ="";
while((line =reader.readLine()) != null){
    htmlData.append(line);
}
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
Pattern.quote("<div class=\"title\"><h2>")+ "(.*?)"
                    +Pattern.quote("</h2>"));
Matcher match = p.matcher(htmlData.toString());
if(match.find()){
    stockName = match.group(1);
}
```

Anyone know how to grab content in other languages from internet using Java inputstream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you didn't specify the character encoding for `InputStreamReader`, so the platform's default charset is accepted. To read Chinese characters use the `UTF-8` charset:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yahooUrl.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Thanks! it is the problem with character encoding you mentioned, but it works with UTF-8.

Comment: Great! Then it's better to use "UTF-8", I'll correct the answer.